# Сброс одних параметров при установке других

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings, properties

По какой-то причине при установке переменных через
     `Properties.Settings.Default`
происходит сброс всех остальных переменных в `Settings` на 0 (Все параметры типа `int`). Устанавливаю значения подобным кодом.

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.Slow_pc = X;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

То есть на кнопку стоит запись определённых переменных для последующей записи в файл, но если параметры не используются кнопкой, то они сбрасывают значение. Возможно, ошибка глупая.

UPD

К примеру есть переменные

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.var1 = 1
 Properties.Settings.Default.var2 = 2
 Properties.Settings.Default.var3 = 3
```

И есть кнопка, которая задаёт переменную `var1` кодом и выписывающая все переменные в файл

```
 private void button1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Properties.Settings.Default.var1 = 4;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    string FileText = Properties.Settings.Default.var1 + "/" + Properties.Settings.Default.var2 +"/"+ Properties.Settings.Default.var3;
    File.WriteAllText(C:/.../File.txt, FileText);
 }
```

Как итог будет выведен файл с текстом

```
   4/0/0
```

а не

```
   4/2/3
```

как ожидалось.

Comment: Уточните, где вы сохраняете настройки - что выставлено в Scope настройках для этих параметров - User или Application. Если User и Вы запускаете один раз с дебага, а в другой раз с папки, такое может быть, потому что для системы это две разные программы.

Comment: @koshe возможно я не точно объяснил. Параметры сбрасываются в пределах одной сессии.

Comment: Такого не должно быть, может приведете полный код, касающиеся выставления настроек и как Вы их проверяете.

Comment: @koshe Я понимаю, что такого быть не должно, поэтому я и обратился за помощью. Я дополнил пост.

Comment: Вы пишете, что _К примеру есть переменные..._, 1,2 и 3 эти значения выставлены в Settings или присвоивается из кода? Если из кода, то в конце должна стоят строка `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`, иначе записываться в файл они не будут. Приведите полный код (если много кода, создайте новый проект и перенесите все, касающиеся параметров).

Comment: Нет, все значения переменные установлены в `Settings`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62436/discussion-between-koshe-and-homid-way).